# Speed up calculation of recursively defined list

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, recursion

I have two lists $a$ and $b$ of length $n$ and $n-1$ respectively (typically I have $n \approx 1000$).
I have to compute a list $\theta$ of length $n$ which is defined recursively by the following relation:
$$
\theta_i = a_i\theta_{i-1} - b_{i-1}^2\theta_{i-2}, \;\;\;\;\; i = 2,...,n
$$
where $\theta_0 = 1$ and $\theta_1 = a_1$.
I can easily code a simple loop that performs this operation:

```
theta[[1]] = a[[1]]; 
theta[[2]] = a[[2]]*theta[[1]] - b[[1]]^2;
Do[
  theta[[i]] = 
    a[[i]]*theta[[i - 1]] - (b[[i - 1]]^2)*theta[[i - 2]];
  , {i, 3, n}];
```

where I have computed explicitly $\theta_2$ for simplicity.

So far so good, but I know that the `Do[]` loops are usually not the best way to go in Mathematica, so I wonder if there is some way to speed up this code. Also consider that I absolutely need to insert this code into `Compile[]`, where the lists $a$ and $b$ are the input of my function. This is because I want to give the attribute Listable to my function for performance reasons.

I know that sometimes there are clever ways to code recursive functions in general, but I really don't know much about this topic, so any help related to some basic concepts of recursive procedures is also appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post  a[i] and b[i].

Comment: a and b can be whatever, this is meant to be a small step inside a function where a and b are the input variables.

Answer (score 3):

A common approach to speed recursive calculations like this is [`memoization`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25150).
In Mathematica, this can be as simple as using the `f[arg_]:=f[arg]=computation` pattern:

```
listOfAs = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 1000];
listOfBs = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 1000];

Clear[theta]
theta[i_] := theta[i] = With[{a = listOfAs[[i]], b = listOfBs[[i - 1]]},
  a theta[i - 1] - b^2 theta[i - 2] ]
theta[0] = 1; theta[1] = listOfAs[[1]];

AbsoluteTiming[theta/@Range[1000];]
```

This only takes a fraction of a second on my machine, so I'd be curious what application you had in mind and whether it indeed requires Compile.

Comment: Thanks! Essentially I am comparing several approaches to compute the top-left element of the inverse matrix of a tridiagonal symmetric matrix. I need the fastest possible algoritm because I apply the function to thousands of matrices. So far I simply use the cofactor method, which is not listable,, but then I found that this can be done with such recursive methods and I was wondering if those could be compiled and made listable

Answer (score 2):

```
a[i_] = i;
b[i_] = -i;
RecurrenceTable[{θ[i] == 
   a[i] θ[i - 1] - b[i - 1]^2 θ[i - 2], θ[0] == 1,
  θ[1] == a[1]}, θ, {i, 1, 1000}]
```